# Accidentally deleted Python3 with Ubuntu. Now so many things dont work

Tags: 14.04, python, administrator

I accidentally deleted

```
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

which had a link to python3. Now i copied python3.6 from

```
/usr/local/python3.6 into usr/bin/python3.6
```

and created a simlink to /usr/bin/python3.

However, now I have so many problems.

1. Software and Update doesnt work
2. Terminal Doesnt open
3. Every time i try to do sudo apt-get install i get

   ```
   reading packages lists.. Done
   Building dependency tree
   reading state information done
   E : The package python3 needs to be reinstalled but cannot find an archive for it.
   ```

Previously i had the same error but it said couldnt find python3-pip. I am so confused and i cannot install a new ubuntu as this is a work machine. Any help appreciated. I think even copy and paste is not working.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT upgrade, downgrade, or otherwise change the installed version of Python2 or Python3. You will break many important system services that rely upon that specific version...as you have already discovered.

Completely uninstall whatever non-Ubuntu version of Python3 you installed.
Disable or delete their apt sources, if any.
Refresh your package database (sudo apt update) if your sources changed.

Replace the system-compatible version of Python3 easily:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3     // Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier
sudo apt install --reinstall python3         // Ubuntu 16.04 and later
```

If you get other missing-file or missing-package errors, reinstall those packages also.

Comment: `apt-get` works on 16.04 as well. It's all still the same :)

Comment: For now, not forever. 'apt' is the future.